# how to control mouse pointer using Wifi udp socket programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets, mouseevent, mousemove

Using my android phone to control mouse of linux laptop
so the mouse has to move acordingly to my finger touch and drags

got to be tcpip(or udp) wifi socket programming between android server and linux server. (so java and C)

how to make linux server in c to move pointer and communicate the coordinates?

should it be using low level read write?
or by using X window library?

Comment: This might help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433447/how-to-set-mouse-cursor-position-in-c-on-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XWarpPointer from XWindows Library does the trick.
http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XWarpPointer.html